# RegEx: Return string that contains no more than two specific characters

Tags: regex

I have hundreds of files that contain arrays of numbers.  The arrays vary in size.  I need to identify which arrays have only three elements and extract their values.

Here are some examples:

```
askjdh fdshajkjashf hjd ([123, 2321, 321, 123, 3425.98]);

askjdh    ljkjsd hjd ([123, 2321, 321.345]);

askjdh w;klejfjk hjd ([123, 2321, 321.345]); % aksdhj

askjdh ljkjsd hjd ([   13, 21  , -45]);
```

The two matches from above should be:

```
askjdh ljkjsd hjd ([123, 2321, 321.345]);

askjdh ljkjsd hjd ([   13, 21  , -45]);
```

And the values are:

```
123, 2321, 321.345

13, 21, -45
```

I thought this would work, but it's not:

```
\[(.*),(.*),(^[^,].*$)\]
```

This does work... but it seems rather bulky.  Perhaps there's something more elegant?

```
\[\s*([-+]?\d+\.?\d*)\s*,\s*([-+]?\d+\.?\d*)\s*,\s*([-+]?\d+\.?\d*)\s*\]
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: In java, to get the length of the array is 'array.length' then to get their values it is 'array[0]; array[1], etc. Is this is what you want?

Comment: Language: I'm using BareGrep to search through all the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\[\s*(?:-?\d*\.?\d+\s*,\s*){2}-?\d*\.?\d+\]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO8zV7/1)**

[image]

It is similar to your regex but using `{2}` notation you can shorten it a little.

Comment: Could you post a link to regex101? I tried something like yours but I think the OP wants to get the numbers (which makes me use capturing braces that I don't see in your answer). ***Edit:*** yes, I saw the link, thanks :)

Comment: @Al.G. there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for exactly three elements, you can use `/\[[^,]+, *[^,]+, *[^\]]+ *\]/`

```
\[[^,]+, *[^,]+, *[^\]]+ *\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RL77wVtX6QTFc83e)

Comment: Hey Tobi, you can even shorten it more with: `/\[( *[^,]+,){2} *[^\]]+ *\]/`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what ***I*** tried to do:

```
\[
  \s*
  (?:
    \s*
    (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
    \s*\,\s*
  )+
  (?: # this is supposed to match the last number, which is not followed by a ","
    \s*
    (\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
    \s*
  )?
\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/zG5eZ5/1

But for some reason, I'm getting only the last two numbers (look at "match information", on the right side), instead of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern w/ `gm` options to extract 3 elements only and their values

```
\(\[\s*([^, ]+)\s*,\s*([^, ]+)\s*,\s*([^, ]+)\s*\]\);$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/174)

Comment: I like this one.  It has the added advantage of capturing exp numbers like 10.02e-23.  I ended up taking the '$' off the end because I actually do need the cases where there is text after the array definition.  I ended up using: \[\s*([^, ]+)\s*,\s*([^, ]+)\s*,\s*([^, ]+)\s*\]